# tesseract v3.03 render PDF with searchable text example

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

From the [tesseract v3.03 's release note](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReleaseNotes#Tesseract_release_notes_Feb_4_2014_=_V3.03_%28rc1%29.), `tesseract` is now supporting render PDF output with searchable text, but I don't know how to use this feature in my code.
Currently I use [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) for my android app, then I just wonder can this feature work for android?

It would be great if you can give me an example that uses `tesseract` api to render pdf, and then I will try to port missing functions for `tess-two` library.
Thanks in advance.

P/s: I can see the [pdfrenderer](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/api/pdfrenderer.cpp) file which may handle render pdf output, but I don't know how to apply it with base api.

**Update**: here is my try:

```
 tesseract::TessResultRenderer* renderer = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(nat->api.GetDatapath());
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Test_tesseract", "data path = %s", nat->api.GetDatapath());
if (!nat->api.ProcessPages(c_file_name, NULL, 0, renderer)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Test_tesseract", "process page failed");
    delete renderer;
    return;
}

FILE* fout = fopen(c_pdf_file_name, "wb");
if (fout == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Test_tesseract", "Cannot create output file %s\n", c_pdf_file_name);
    delete renderer;
    return;
}

const char* data;
int dataLength;

bool boolValue = renderer->GetOutput(&data, &dataLength);
if (boolValue) {
    fwrite(data, 1, dataLength, fout);
    if (fout != stdout)
        fclose(fout);
    else
        clearerr(fout);
}else{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Test_tesseract", "Cannot get output file");
}
    
delete renderer;
```

My code is failed at `ProcessPages` method. After write log (I have a problem with debugging in ndk), I found pdfrender `BeginDocument` always return false in `TessBaseAPI::ProcessPages` method of `baseapi.cpp`:

```
if (renderer && !renderer->BeginDocument(kUnknownTitle)) {
    success = false;
 }
```

Do I miss something?
P/s: I use `tess-two`, which prefer `baseapi` to `capi`

Comment: Hi @R4j, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: actually, I don't have time to finish it, and I quit this project before

Comment: I wish to continue this, but I can't seem to find a way to debug the native cpp code in Eclipse, what program do you use to debug?

Comment: I just write to logcat. If you want, I can share to you my try

Comment: That will be great! How may I contact you? (can't find your email)

Comment: Here you are: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p99pj81djtv8ved/tess-two-export.rar  I'm not sure this is a right way for rendering pdf, but you can give it a try

Comment: Thanks @R4j! Will give it a try when I get some free time :) Do you mind to give me your email though? I don't understand why stackoverflow make it so hard to send private message for offline discussions.. you can drop me a message at my website's contact page www.thesimplest.net/contact and I'll email you privately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's as follows:

```
TessResultRenderer renderer = api.TessPDFRendererCreate(dataPath);
api.TessBaseAPIProcessPages1(handle, image, null, 0, renderer);
PointerByReference data = new PointerByReference();
IntByReference dataLength = new IntByReference();
api.TessResultRendererGetOutput(renderer, data, dataLength);
byte[] bytes = data.getValue().getByteArray(0, dataLength);
// then write bytes array to a file with PDF extension.
```

If you have problem following the codes, check out the renderer example in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/tesseract-dev/xXplYPiZCZI).

Comment: I updated my question with implement code for android but still not work. Could you take a look at this?

Comment: It looks correct. It could be something in `tess-two` implementation of the new `Renderer` api.

Comment: actually, `tess-two` use original tesseract source code without modifying. They just added some classes to call `tesseract` api. I want to know **are there any conditions for rendering pdf?**. After reading `pdfrenderer.cpp`, I found that `pdf.ttf` and `pdf.ttx` files are required. I added these files into tessdata folder, BeginDocument method can work now. But there are some issues while reading file. For example, `pix = pixRead(pagename);` always return `NULL`

Comment: Hi, I'm using tess-two too, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @Bruce I haven't worked on this project for a long time. But as I remember, I just generate successful pdf from tiff image, not for other types.

Comment: Hi @nguyenq , with R4j's help I got it to work only with one particular PNG image file that I have. I tried other tiff image, jpg image, or even other PNG images and they were not able to render the PDF. Do you know if tesseract PDF render only supports image files with special properties? Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce, I have success with PNG and TIFF images using the latest revision r1111 from Tesseract code repository, which fixed a image file load issue and removed some API methods listed above.

Comment: @nguyenq Thanks for the info! Does it work with JPG too?

Comment: @nguyenq Can I have your email contact? I have two PNG files with one of them able to generate PDF, while the other one failing badly. Could you help me to try them and see whether you're able to generate PDF from them? You can drop me a message at my website's contact page www.thesimplest.net/contact and I'll email you privately. Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce: I converted the TIFF to JPG and could generate PDF with that JPG also.

Comment: @nguyenq I manage to get it to work after adding and linking libjpeg to leptonica. I've generated the PDF successfully and it can be opened with the PDF viewer on my android phone, or even browsers on my PC. However when I try to open it using Foxit PDF Reader on my PC it crashes everytime. Is it because of PDF format being used? Can we specify the PDF format that we would like to produce?